# MS Deploy - deploy a folder to a website

Tags: msdeploy

I have a compiled website, with the correct web config in a folder ready to be deployed. FYI its not zip/packaged.

how (or can) I use MSDeploy to sync the folder with my website (the site supports MS deploy and have been enabled.)

one of my attempts have been:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\my folder" -dest:iisApp="subdomain.mysite.com"
```

which provides this error:
ContentPath and iisApp are not compatible for the given operation.

I have also included the userName and Password on the destination.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Got it to work!!!!

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\my folder" -dest:contentPath="subdomain.mysite.com",wmsvc=hostServer.com,userName=usr,password=pwd -AllowUntrusted
```

-wmsvc - defaults to port 8172

-AllowUntrusted - to allow untrusted certificates

hope this helps any one else.

Answer (score 9):

dbones' answer resolves the "ContentPath and iisApp are not compatible" error by switching the -dest parameter to use the contentPath provider, thereby making -source and -dest have the same provider.

One can alternatively resolve the error by switching the -dest parameter to use the iisApp parameter. This sort of thing works, for example:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:iisapp="C:\fooapp" -dest:iisapp="MyWebsite/fooapp",computerName=localhost
```

One advantage/difference of this method is that, on the first deployment of fooapp, this will create MyWebsite/fooapp as an actual web application, rather than as a normal directory.

Comment: omg I would never had thought iisapp could have a path as a source! thx